# How does msvc compiler(and other compilers) knows which std overload to bind to?

Tags: c++, stl, std, static-linking

I know this question has two answers - one very long and complicated and one rather short and simple. For now, I am interested in the latter.

I am coming from C#/.NET background and if you used it for a while (or Java) you will probably agree with me that whenever you use some BCL class or methods is relatively easy to deduce why certain overload is chosen by the compiler.

Simple example of C#

```
// lets imagine we have this somewhere in our code
Contract.Requires(e != null);

// we check who implements this method ...

public static void Requires(bool condition); // <-- observing the call its pretty obvious that this method will be chosen instead of the others
public static void Requires<TException>(bool condition, string userMessage) where TException : Exception;
public static void Requires<TException>(bool condition) where TException : Exception;
public static void Requires(bool condition, string userMessage);
```

If you haven't already figured out I am still trying to learn C++, so I will give a simple example and hopefully I will start feeling more comfortable reading std code after this question.

```
// we have this call
int ints[5];
std::is_heap(std::begin(ints), std::end(ints));

// first method I tried to unwind was std::begin and std::end
// and this is what I got from Visual Studio as suggestion (and later confirmed by runtime)

template <class _Ty, size_t _Size>
_NODISCARD constexpr _Ty* begin(_Ty (&_Array)[_Size]) noexcept {
    return _Array;
}

template <class _Ty, size_t _Size>
_NODISCARD constexpr _Ty* end(_Ty (&_Array)[_Size]) noexcept {
    return _Array + _Size;
}

// then I checked std::is_heap and I got

template <class _RanIt>
_NODISCARD bool is_heap(_RanIt _First, _RanIt _Last) { // test if range is a heap ordered by operator<
    return _STD is_heap(_First, _Last, less<>());
}
```

I guess I will remind you of my disclaimer that I am new to C++ before I make some assumptions.

1. Is `(&_Array)[_Size]` some way of helping compiler understand that parameter passed to a certain function (or function template) will be array (something like `type_traits`)?
2. In the second static binding (std::is_heap), is it because templates are compile-time and therefore suggested function cannot look the way you expect it to look, for instance, something of sort `is_heap(int*, int*)` since these are the argument types you are calling it with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is (&_Array)[_Size] some way of helping compiler understand that parameter passed to a certain function (or function template) will be array (something like type_traits)?

`_Ty (&_Array)[_Size]` is an array argument (a `_Ty[_Size]`), passed by reference and named `_Array`. It looks weird 'cos C, believe it or not. Nothing to do with type traits.

I don't really understand your second question, but the compiler picks the overload that best matches your arguments. The rules on what "best" means here are complex but described in the standard. If multiple overloads match equally, your call is ambiguous and the program will not compile. Templates do complicate this as they introduce *many* possible candidates by their very nature. I do agree that the template is likely to be instantiated here with `_RanIt=int*`, and the result is a perfect match for your call.

Comment: So my second guess was right, very well then, not sure I understood the first one tho but I will give it some time to sink in

Comment: @kuskmen I think it's just the syntax confusing you. An `int` passed by value looks like `void foo(int x)`. A `_Ty` passed by value looks like `void foo(_Ty x)`. A `_Ty` passed by reference looks like `void foo(_Ty& x)`. A `_Ty[_Size]` passed by reference looks like `void foo(_Ty (&x)[_Size])`. That's just how it is. Look up the "spiral rule" for more on complex declarations (the syntax/rule is inherited from C)

Comment: Ah now I get it, but what bugs me is that you are passing the size implicitly as well, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @kuskmen N.B. an array "passed by value" (i.e. `void foo(_Ty x[_Size])`) is a _lie_! That's equivalent to `void foo(_Ty* x)`, even though arrays are not pointers. Again, blame C. :)

Comment: @kuskmen Yes, the size of an array is part of its type. An `int[5]` is a different kind of thing to a `int[10]`.

Comment: Does this mean that if other data is part of the type we can get the way we get the size? Is there some wording or documentation I can search for over the internet? I want to elaborate on this

Comment: saying that `int[5]` and `int[10]` are different types helped me understand, I think this is not the case in C# but I might be wrong tho

Comment: C# is quite different; I'd advise trying not to make comparisons between the two languages.